# Is it possible to detect the key for the array within the Rails params hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I'm using a inherited controller for an abstracted class.  I'm trying to avoid overriding actions within all of the descendant controllers.  How could I find out the name of the key where the array of form values is living?  For example:

The master class currently uses this to update rows

```
if @parent.update_attributes(params[:parent])
```

Every class that inherits from it has its own name that will not be recognized

```
<input type="text" value="" name="child[title]" id="child_title">
```

How can I dynamically detect the :name I need to use in the params[ ] for each form?  I would settle for some form_for guidance for my partial that handles edit and new:

```
form_for @parent do |f|
```

I've tried what is below but I can't get it to do PUT.  When I edit it makes a new row:

```
form_for @child, :as => :parent, :url => child_path do |f|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the name of the key all along in my instance variable.  I just didn't know how to get it out and turn it into the symbol I needed for the params hash.  Here is how I did it:

```
@element.update_attributes(params[@element.class.name.downcase.to_sym])
```

This way I can make a resource, have it inherit from a parent controller, use the default form setup, and still recycle the logic from the parent controller.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really undestand what you are asking about. So I beg your pardon if my answer is not relevant.

1.As I understood the first thing you are looking for is to how map the particular the key in params hash with the actual descendant controller which has made post/put request. You can do so by examining "controller_name" something like that:

`keys = {
      'ChildController1' => :child1,
      'ChildController1' => :child2,
    }`

```
key = key[controller.controller_name]
@model.update_attributes(params[key])
```

2.If you need to perform a put request add `:html => {:method => :put}` as the last param of form_for method of FormBuilder helper (`form_for @resource, :url => {resource_path(@resource)}, :html => {:method => :put}`

Comment: You pretty much understood what I was asking.  What you suggested would work, but it is kind of fragile because I would have to maintain a hash of children.  I need a method that would help me scrape the key of the array that is generated by a rails form.  I am trying to do this so I don't have to use the :method => :put and :method => :post in two separate partials or repeat myself in controllers.